# how to display a text inside an image that is rendered inside a jQuery image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am building a web site using asp.net mvc web application + JQuery + Bootstrap 3.

now i am using a web template which provides an image gallery , and when i click on an image inside the image gallery,  an image slider will be shown. now the markup for a single image inside the image gallery is :-

```
  <ul class="listgall">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6  col-xs-6 colgal">
                        <figure><a href="img/slide_image1.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="img/gallery_image1.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:<strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span></a></figure>
                    </li>
```

now as shown on the above markup, inside the image gallery an image named `gallery_image1.jpg` will be shown when the page loads, and when i hover over it a text will be shown

```
<span><strong>Project name:<strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span>
```

[image]

Now if i click on the above image, another image named `slide_image1.jpg` will be shown inside an image slider.

The problem i am facing is that the image inside the slider will not have any text when i hover over it ,, unlike the image inside the image gallery. so can anyone adivce how i can show a fixed text inside the image when rendered inside a slider ?

here is a sample of the web template image slider i am working on  http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/index-2.html

Comment: How is `<span><strong>Project name:<strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span>` rendered over image ? Is requirement to display same `html` over image , or text ? Can include `js` , `css` at Question ?

Comment: So to test and answer your Question one should create from scratch an example guessing your styles and all?

Comment: @guest271314 well inside the slider i was planning to provide more detailed text , so if it is possible to define different text this will be better..

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you are correct, but i have similar example on this link http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/index-2.html it is the same as the template i am currently using

Answer (score 1):

Find the [**jQuery's touchTouch plugin**   code](https://github.com/martinaglv/touchTouch) in `js/touchTouch.jquery.js`.
It's well commented and you should be able to easily modify the overlay gallery view in order to add the desired stuff in it for every slide.
So there's no *Bootstrap* magic here. Style everything you need in CSS. Reuse some styles you already have if needed.

Comment: but i need to specify the text i want to render inside a span is this correct, then i should force the tochTouch script to read this span ?

Comment: @johnG exactly. Don't think about that as *forcing*... It's not Forcing, it's simply about *modifying*. The script is fairly easy to understand and it's well commented.

Comment: so i need to add a span with the required text inside my web page markup , then i specify inside the script to read the related span inside the slider ,, is this correct?